# Qt Creator temporary files

Tags: qt, qtquick2

I noticed empty (0 KB) files in my project directory without extension. Examples of the names of this files: `usersadzolappdatalocaltemptmp8eyiqb`, `usersadzolappdatalocaltemptmpfdqpqc`. My project use C++ and QML.

How I can get rid on this files?

Comment: Are you building in the project dir, or (better) in some other directory?

Comment: In the project directory.